# Can Adobe Air track other native windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, window, adobe, native

I searched and only found one question like mine which was 6 years ago and the only answer was "No".

So, today, is it possible to track or detect any other native windows in Windows using Adobe Air? If it is not, what stops it from being able to do this and are there any work arounds for something similar?

What I am trying to do is overlay a button onto another popular game when a match is finished. To do this I would need to know the position, length, and height of the game window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the AIR runtime doesn't provide access to OS windows other than ones managed by AIR. So in that sense, no it's not possible.

However you could write your own [Native Extension](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html) (or possibly just use [`NativeProcess`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)) to create your own AS3 API for manipulating Windows windows.